# Conditioning a piezoelectric sensor via a charge amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, piezoelectricity, signal-conditioning

I am trying to use a charge amplifier to condition a piezoelectric disc bender (APC International #20-1205).

This is my current schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faZbUc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using a DC power supply to test the op amp and see if the charge amplifier works

When I vary my source from 0 to 6 V, the output still stays around -10 V (very close to supply voltage), and only changes by about 0.3 V at the most.

I have checked all my wiring, connections, and components for errors and have not found any. I'm convinced I have made a mistake somewhere but cannot seem to find what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any help

Comment: When you say you vary your source from 0 to 6 V, do you mean applying a positive voltage to R2?

Comment: The resistors makes the gain about 66. So the only way how to test it is feed input with -150 to +150mV signal.

Comment: @evildemonic yes

Comment: Ok.  Your circuit will rail negative if you provide more than about 150 mV.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate the pieso sensor by applying an input voltage through the capacitor C_s (or the very sensor) in series. Then the charge amplifier's gain will be determined by the ratio between the two capacitors. The resistor R2 is too high; decrease its resistance.

You can find an intuitive explanation of this clever circuit in [my Codidact paper](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/278836).